# Wasserstein distance, convex polytopes and extreme points

Tags: pr.probability, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

Let us consider convex polytopes with $K$ extreme points in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $\mathbf{P}$ be such polytope, and let $\text{ext}(\mathbf{P})$ denote its set of extreme points, so that $\mathbf{P} = \text{conv}(\text{ext}(\mathbf{P}))$ and $|\text{ext}(\mathbf{P})| =K$.

Let $\mathcal{L}|_{\mathbf{P}}$ be the uniform distribution on $\mathbf{P}$, or in other words, the restriction of $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure to $\mathbf{P}$. Also, let 
$$\mathbb{P}_{\mathbf{P}} := \frac{1}{K} \sum_{x \in \text{ext}(\mathbf{P})} \delta_x$$ 
be the empirical measure on the extreme points of $\mathbf{P}$, that is the discrete uniform distribution on $\text{ext}(\mathbf{P})$.

Consider [Wasserstein-$p$ distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) between probability measures, for $p=1$ or $2$.  We are interested in 
$$
W_p(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbf{P}},\mathcal{L}|_{\mathbf{P}}).
$$
Is there a way to characterize it? For what polytopes $\mathbf{P}$, this distance is the smallest (largest)?

Comment: Do you consider the polytope $P$ to be the set of points on or inside the hull, or is $P$ the boundary of the hull? Presumably you mean the former.

Comment: Yes, the I mean the former.

Comment: Have you computed the case of the segment $[0,1]$?

Comment: You should also state the metric on $\mathbb{R}^d$ you use (presumably the euclidean metric).

Comment: @alvarezpaiva, no, I haven't tried, but thanks for pointing it out. I was more thinking about triangles as the simplest examples, since in that case, there is some variety, which is not present in the case $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Dirk, Yes, let's take the metric to be the Euclidean metric.

Comment: It may be worth noting that your distance is the average, over vertices x of P, of the average distance (squared) from x to a point in the Voronoi cell of P associated to x.

Comment: And incidentally, the distance can be made arbitrarily large or small unless you impose some other constraint (fixed volume, perhaps?).